# fixed menu bar makes Scrolling jerky in Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have created a webpage styled with a fixed menu bar using CSS and JAVA script. My menu bar get fixed to page when we scroll below menu bar height. It works fine in all browsers except Safari. Scrolling gets jerky when menu bar get fixed to the web page in Safari. When I change css position:relative; scrolling works fine, but i want a fixed menu. Please help.
Here's my html code for menu

```
<div>
 <nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#screen1"><img src="css/images/logo.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#screen2"><strong>About Us</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#screen3"><strong>Products</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#screen6"><strong>Manufacturing Process</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#screen7"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
```

Here's my css for menu

```
.fixed {
    font-family: 'lubalgraph_bk_btbook';
    position: fixed; 
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    top: 0; 
    width:100%;
    height: 17%;
    background: #f1f2f2;
    opacity: 0.8; 
    z-index: 1;
    min-width: 960px;
}
```

Here's my java script

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
       var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 70;
             if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
                 $('nav').addClass('fixed');
             }
             else {
                 $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
             }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance................

Comment: When I remove background images website works fine but I cant remove images as I dont't want to compromise with look. You can check website http://www.hfpplexim.com/